# BIT(1) vs ENUM('unknown', 'male', 'female') in MySQL

Tags: mysql, performance, optimization, enums, bit

In performance terms, what will be faster, use a `BIT(1) NULL` (null = unknown, 0 = male, 1 = female) or `ENUM('unknown', 'male', 'female') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'unknown'` in **MySQL MyISAM**?

Or this is considered **micro-optimization**?

[EDIT]

I think I'm going to use `ENUM('male', 'female') DEFAULT NULL`

Comment: Micro-optimization. Choose whatever is more meaningful/semantically correct.

Comment: Faster in performance terms for doing what? Inserting millions of rows of data? Querying for all users of a particular gender? Something else?

Comment: Null doesn't quite exactly mean "unknown" and it can cause a mess with your SQL queries. First of all, dealing with null means wacky extra syntax you can avoid. Second, there's the funny illogic of computing with null, where null compared to anything is null. And what if a eunich comes along?

Comment: Nice to see how so many people know this is a micro-optimization wihtout knowing what will happen with this column.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is microoptimization. Performance will be dominated by other things, and anyway nullable fields take more space (for a null flag) so use the meaningful enumeration.

Answer (score 1):

I consider this micro-optimization.

I would go for the ENUM option, because the meaning of all values is completely clear without reading documentation. The bit option is a bit vague.

Regarding performance, I seem to remember NULL is usually bad, but can't find references right now.